# React Redux form and connect syntax

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, redux-form

I have a React component

```
export class Login extends Component {
      ..omitted for clarity
}
export default connect(select, actions)(Login);
```

And as can be seen it connects to Redux and it works perfectly well

I have Redux Form as

```
export class ChangePassword extends Component {
  ..omitted for clarity
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'change_password_form',
  validate
})(ChangePassword);
```

Again this is working perfectly well.

My question is , I can't work out the syntax to have the Redux form also to use the connect statement e.g. `connect(select, actions)`

Something like this ?

```
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'change_password_form',
  validate
}).connect(select, actions)(ChangePassword)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since the `connect` method decorates the original component, and returns a decorated component, you can pass that component to `reduxForm` ([Redux Form FAQ](https://redux-form.com/6.7.0/docs/faq/howtoconnect.md/)).

You can see an example in the docs.

```
const decoratedComponent = connect(select, actions)(ChangePassword)

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'change_password_form',
  validate
})(DecoratedComponent)
```

Or pass it directly:

```
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'change_password_form',
  validate
})(connect(select, actions)(ChangePassword))
```

If you need to get data from the store, for example - [to create the form's initial values from the state](http://for%20example), you can wrap the original component with redux-form, and pass the "form" component to `connect`:

```
export default connect(select, actions)(reduxForm({
  form: 'change_password_form',
  validate
})(ChangePassword))
```

Or you can use functional composing with a `compose` method (from [redux](https://redux.js.org/api/compose)/[lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#flowRight)/[ramda](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#compose) for example), to call `reduxForm`, and then `connect` on the component:

```
export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
  reduxForm({ form: 'change_password_form', validate })
)(ChangePassword)
```

Comment: thanks, I used . instead of (),  I used the direct  statement from your example

Comment: Welcome. I've added another example for wrapping the form with connect.

Comment: when I use the last option since I need to get data from state into redux-form, I get this error :
```Uncaught Invariant Violation: You must pass a component to the function returned by connect. ```

Comment: @Bromox and for everyone that get this problem: I found a solution though. I described it in my post so I hope it will help you and you will understand what happened - codemenatalie.com/blog/connecting-redux-form-and-connect/

Answer (score 1):

Applying multiple middlewares works like this:

```
middlewareB(middlewareA(Component))
```

In your case:

```
export default connect(select, actions)(reduxForm({})(ChangePassword))
```

Answer (score 1):

I can guarantee this works, TypeScript herein optional:

(I am using combineReducer, hence the nested state imported to the component props.)

Here <any, any, any> is respectively, mapStateToProps, imported Action Creators, and the React Component wrapped with Redux Form.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
  currentItems: state.itemsReducer.currentItem,
  initialValues: state.itemsReducer.currentItem,
  keepDirtyOnReinitialize: true,
});

//ReduxForm decorator populates the initialValues prop 
//from Connect into Field components with its library functionality:
export default connect<any, any, any>(mapStateToProps, {
  CreateItem,
  UpdateItem,
  getItemById
})(reduxForm({
  form: 'ItemsForm'
})(AddItemToList))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a wrapper class above the redux form and connect that to redux. And you can simply pass the props from that wrapper class to the redux form. Something like this:

```
//redux form
export class ChangePassword extends Component {
  ..omitted for clarity
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'change_password_form',
  validate
})(ChangePassword);

// wrapper class
export class FormWrapper extends React.Component {
  // omitted for clarity
}

export default connect(select, actions)(FormWrapper);
```