# Redux Forms Field not populating values

Tags: reactjs, redux, field, redux-form, reducers

This is my code in my form component:

```
{console.log('Value matching name for Field: ', props.initialValues.name)}
                    <Field
                      name="name"
                      //also tried name="props.initialValues.name"
                      component="input"
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Name required"
                    />
```

The console log correctly outputs the name value needed.

The `<Field/>` component never shows the name value that is console logged.

I cannot find an answer in RF documentation or anywhere else.

Using ReduxForms version 8.

Comment: Do you want `name={props.initialValues.name}`?

Comment: That would make sense, but I just tried that and nothing showed in the Field.

Comment: can you show how do you use the reduxForm wrapper with initial values?

Comment: Please see my answer to this posting. This wrapper is working perfectly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46791190/react-redux-form-and-connect-syntax/65235420#65235420